# Can I be forced to keep my Wikipedia account?

Tags: wikipedia

I have an account on the [Scratch Wiki](https://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/User:Minerman6) but I have been informed by the site that I am not allowed to delete this.

I have had several messages informing me that I am not allowed to delete the data that I posted on the site. I want to remove my data and my account but I keep getting warning messages. I want to get rid of this website. I am outraged by the treatment that they have given me, surely I have rights to what data and accounts I have online.

How should I go about deleting my account and removing my data from the site?

What legal rights do I have surrounding this?

UPDATE
I have contacted Scratch about this and they replied:

> As an EU citizen, you have the right not to have your data on EU sites. This is the Scratch Wiki. The same terms of service apply to this site as the Scratch site. Scratch's terms of service state that US law applies. 
>   Besides this, you agreed to have your information posted on this site when you posted it. Even if your talk page is blanked, other users can see previous revisions using the page history. Even if it's deleted, admins can still see deleted revisions, amounting to the same thing. 
>   If you want to blank your talk page, please discuss it with other users first. Once a consensus has been reached, further action can be taken. However, your talk page should never be deleted - it is a place for other Wikians to contact you. THANK YOU FOR READING THIS. IF YOU SKIPPED OVER IT, GO BACK AND READ IT.

I am told I have to discuss leaving with other users.

Why is my decision to leave the website in the hands of non-qualified people?

The site has an age demographic of under 13 so how are minors allowed to decide whether I am allowed to keep my account?

How do I delete the account?

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone here can help you with these issues.  As Pnuts mentioned in their answer, we are not in a position to give you any legal advice, and the remainder of the questions you've posed about who is making the decision are largely moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content published by Scratch Wiki is published under a CC Attribution / Share-Alike 3.0 licence ([Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-happens-if-the-author-decides-to-revoke-the-cc-license-to-material-i-am-using)), which is non-revocable:

> **What if I change my mind about using a CC license?**
>
> CC licenses are not revocable. Once something has been published under a CC license, licensees may continue using it according to the license terms for the duration of applicable copyright and similar rights. As a licensor, you may stop distributing under the CC license at any time, but anyone who has access to a copy of the material may continue to redistribute it under the CC license terms. While you cannot revoke the license, CC licenses do provide a mechanism for licensors to ask that others using their material remove the attribution information. You should think carefully before choosing a Creative Commons license.

and:

> **What happens if the author decides to revoke the CC license to material I am using?**
>
> The CC licenses are irrevocable. This means that once you receive material under a CC license, you will always have the right to use it under those license terms, even if the licensor changes his or her mind and stops distributing under the CC license terms. Of course, you may choose to respect the licensor’s wishes and stop using the work.

Legal advice however is off topic here (IMO) though I doubt MIT is legally entitled to force you to retain your account (that is, maintain a public connection between your personal details and the content you have contributed). SE for example is prepared to consider deletion of a user's account while retaining the Q&As such a (former) user has posted.

Comment: please see the update.